# Problem with put sld in geoserver

Tags: geoserver, sld, ajax

I want to send SLD to GeoServer via AJAX:
this is my SLD as XML format:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
    xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <NamedLayer>
        <Name>test</Name>
        <UserStyle>
            <Title>test</Title>
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Rule>
                    <PointSymbolizer>
                        <Graphic>
                            <Mark>
                                <WellKnownName>circle</WellKnownName>
                                <Fill>
                                    <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
                                    <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.4</CssParameter>
                                </Fill>
                            </Mark>
                            <Size>3</Size>
                        </Graphic>
                    </PointSymbolizer>
                    <TextSymbolizer>
                        <Label>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>Type</ogc:PropertyName>
                        </Label>
                        <Stroke>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-width">15</CssParameter>
                        </Stroke>
                    </TextSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>
        </UserStyle>
    </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

```
$.ajax({
            url: url + '/geoserver/rest/workspaces/'+ workspace +'/styles/'+ name +'',
            beforeSend: function(xhr) { 
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("admin:geoserver")); 
            },
            type: 'PUT',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/vnd.ogc.sld+xml',
            processData: false,
            async:false,
            data: "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>" + (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(StyledLayerDescriptor),
            success: function (data , textStatus, xhr) {
                console.log('status',xhr.status)
            },
            error: function(ex){
                console.log('ex',ex)
            }
        });
```

after sending, the content of SLD is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><sld:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" version="1.0.0">
  <sld:NamedLayer>
    <sld:Name>Default Styler</sld:Name>
    <sld:UserStyle>
      <sld:Name>Default Styler</sld:Name>
      <sld:Title>test</sld:Title>
      <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <sld:Name>name</sld:Name>
        <sld:Rule>
          <sld:PointSymbolizer>
            <sld:Graphic>
              <sld:Mark>
                <sld:WellKnownName>circle</sld:WellKnownName>
                <sld:Fill>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#000000</sld:CssParameter>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.4</sld:CssParameter>
                </sld:Fill>
              </sld:Mark>
              <sld:Size>3</sld:Size>
            </sld:Graphic>
          </sld:PointSymbolizer>
          <sld:TextSymbolizer>
            <sld:Label>
              <ogc:PropertyName>Type</ogc:PropertyName>
            </sld:Label>
            <sld:LabelPlacement>
              <sld:PointPlacement>
                <sld:AnchorPoint>
                  <sld:AnchorPointX>0.0</sld:AnchorPointX>
                  <sld:AnchorPointY>0.5</sld:AnchorPointY>
                </sld:AnchorPoint>
              </sld:PointPlacement>
            </sld:LabelPlacement>
          </sld:TextSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
      </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </sld:UserStyle>
  </sld:NamedLayer>
</sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Why some XML nodes isn't sent and some extra XML nodes sent?

---

How about this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
    xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <NamedLayer>
        <Name>test</Name>
        <UserStyle>
            <Title>test</Title>
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Rule>
                    <PointSymbolizer>
                        <Graphic>
                            <Mark>
                                <WellKnownName>circle</WellKnownName>
                                <Fill>
                                    <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
                                    <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.4</CssParameter>
                                </Fill>
                                <Stroke>
                                    <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
                                    <CssParameter name="stroke-width">15</CssParameter>
                                </Stroke>
                            </Mark>
                            <Size>3</Size>
                        </Graphic>
                    </PointSymbolizer>
                    <TextSymbolizer>
                        <Label>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>Type</ogc:PropertyName>
                        </Label>
                        <Fill>
                            <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
                        </Fill>
                    </TextSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>
        </UserStyle>
    </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

but in GeoServer SLD is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><sld:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" version="1.0.0">
  <sld:NamedLayer>
    <sld:Name>Default Styler</sld:Name>
    <sld:UserStyle>
      <sld:Name>Default Styler</sld:Name>
      <sld:Title>test</sld:Title>
      <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <sld:Name>name</sld:Name>
        <sld:Rule>
          <sld:PointSymbolizer>
            <sld:Graphic>
              <sld:Mark>
                <sld:WellKnownName>circle</sld:WellKnownName>
                <sld:Fill>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#000000</sld:CssParameter>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.4</sld:CssParameter>
                </sld:Fill>
                <sld:Stroke>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-width">15</sld:CssParameter>
                </sld:Stroke>
              </sld:Mark>
              <sld:Size>3</sld:Size>
            </sld:Graphic>
          </sld:PointSymbolizer>
          <sld:TextSymbolizer>
            <sld:Label>
              <ogc:PropertyName>Type</ogc:PropertyName>
            </sld:Label>
            <sld:LabelPlacement>
              <sld:PointPlacement>
                <sld:AnchorPoint>
                  <sld:AnchorPointX>0.0</sld:AnchorPointX>
                  <sld:AnchorPointY>0.5</sld:AnchorPointY>
                </sld:AnchorPoint>
              </sld:PointPlacement>
            </sld:LabelPlacement>
            <sld:Fill>
              <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#000000</sld:CssParameter>
            </sld:Fill>
          </sld:TextSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
      </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </sld:UserStyle>
  </sld:NamedLayer>
</sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

GeoServer remove

```
<CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
```

It is valid based on GeoServer document. Why?

Comment: It's likely that GeoServer drops invalid SLD elements and adds in default values in the round trip through the parser.

Answer (score 2):

Your SLD input file is invalid - there is no `Stroke` element for [`TextSymbolizer`s](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/reference/textsymbolizer.html) so GeoServer discards those elements when it parses your input file to convert it into a style.

The "extra" elements are default values that GeoServer writes out in full as they are "filled in" in the internal style object so they get serialised out when you ask for the SLD to be generated.

Comment: tnx . How about below Sld ???

Comment: Its a default (so gets left out) I started handling defaults and got bored when writing the serialiser code. The two slds are functionally identical.